# Update undefined in sailsjs model afterCreate hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

In my sailsjs app, I'm trying to add a default avatar for my user after the user is created so I have this afterCreate hook in `models/User.js`:

```
var User = {
  // ...
  attributes: {
    avatar: { model: 'Image' },
    // ...
  },
  afterCreate: function(user, next){
    var url =  sails.config.s3 + "/" + sails.config.default_avatar;
    sails.log.info(user); // This displays the proper user
    var data = { url: url, isAvatar: true, user: user.id };

    Image.create(data) 
    .exec( function (err, image) {
      sails.log.info(image); // This displays the proper image
      User.update(image.user, { avatar: image.id})
      .exec( sails.log.info );
    });
    next();
  },   
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
 /Users/rcanty/Workspace/project/server/api/models/User.js:55
  return User.update(image.user, { avatar: image.id}).exec( sails.log.info
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/rcanty/Workspace/project/server/api/models/User.js:55:19   
at bound (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:416:80)
at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:315:18)
at callback.success (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
at _switch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:48:28)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:241:9
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
at bound.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/schema.js:151:44)
at fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:60:10)
at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:149:13)
at Object.async.eachSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:165:9)
at Object.runner.afterCreate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:63:9)
at after (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:236:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:223:67
at bound (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
```

However it seems like I'm doing exactly what's prescribed in the [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md)

Comment: Did you create this or did you generate it with sails?  I don't see where you are exporting this

Comment: I added this method to the user class after it was generated by sails-auth-generate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this type of thing should be inside your User controller, not inside the model.  Your trying to modify a model that you are defining inside the model you are defining.

Move it to the controller and call it at the end of your createUser function.

EDIT:

Try moving the function outside the attributes object, and add `var User = this;`, so that it can reference itself:

```
  var User = {
    // ...
    attributes: {
      avatar: {model: 'Image'},
      // ...
    },
    afterCreate: function(user, next){
      var url =  sails.config.s3 + "/" + sails.config.default_avatar;
      sails.log.info(user); // This displays the proper user
      var data = { url: url, isAvatar: true, user: user.id };
      var User = this; // for internal reference

      Image.create(data)
          .exec( function (err, image) {
            sails.log.info(image); // This displays the proper image
            User.update(image.user, { avatar: image.id})
                .exec( sails.log.info );
          });
      next();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I actually disagree with that design practice, though I'll try it out today to see if it works. If I can't add a default image to a user in the afterCreate callback, which IMO is where it should be, that seems like a pretty big Sails design flaw since you can do this in one line in Rails.

Comment: Well..hang on let me look at that generator...I'm not familiar with what it gives you.  The auth package I'm using doesn't do it quite the same way.

Comment: I haven't tested it by the way, but referencing the model from within itself still seems off.

Comment: Thanks so much, but actually that was a mistake on my part in the post not the code. I actually already had the method outside the attributes. Thanks to you're suggestion, I added the line `var User = this` outside the call to image and now it works. If you update your answer to reflect this, I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah I just tested it. If you log the this of the user, you'll see the update function. You were right that User wast defined in the Image callback context yet since it hadn't been exported, which happens at the end of the file.